# create laravel passport token based on project

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

The user can have more than one project, so I need to create a separate token for every project. if any operation trigger using API then I need to check they have access to that particular project or not.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think creating separate tokens is the solution here. What you need to do is use scopes.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport#token-scopes

Please refer this

Comment: there I can't create dynamic scope. because I need to register scope static. is there any other way to creating dynamic scope

Comment: Okay. Use this package https://github.com/benbjurstrom/passport-custom-jwt-claims to set custom claims based on type of user and then validating those claims when the user logs-in.